# Multiple Connected apps for oauth

Tags: oauth2, authentication, connected-apps, refresh-token

I have a web application that has a mobile component. Both of them have Salesforce oAuth and use different connected apps. Sometimes users authenticate only via the mobile app and their credentials are shared with the web app to allow Salesforce integration.

At times I am unable to refresh their tokens using the second connected app, would there be an issue using two connected apps and sharing refresh_tokens between them?